# Sublime Text 2 - is there smart intellisense with hints for jquery (not snippets!)

Tags: jquery, intellisense, sublimetext2

how can i achieve the same level of details i get when using vs2012 in my light weight **sublime text 2**. all the packages i tried are dealing mostly with snippets (rather than sniffing for smart hints). in vs2012 i solved it using -vsdoc. how can i solve it with sublime?

[image: the effect i'm looking for]

i'm sure there has to be a way for sublime text 2 to somehow parse the function and understand what kind of parameters i should be using in order to get my way. please don't refer me to google. i've searched everywhere.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*i'm extending the question to the javascript language:*

The best packages for JavaScript auto-completion in **sublime text 2 & 3** are the TernJS ones. it analyzes your code to bring you smart contextual suggestions. it's still not what we're use to from c#/java IDEs but it's better than the native option. also it somewhat slows sublime from time to time.

b.t.w - you can also use the jquery tailored packages from the registry.

you might want to go another way - **brackets** has a built in autocomplete for javascript (also tern based). I found it to be much better than the sublime package.

commercial wise: **webstorm** is the closest you'll get to VS intellisense and perfect suggestions. I've tested it on node.js and it surprised me with its quick and efficient completions. better than the above but it does cost money after trial period.

Answer (score 5):

The person who wrote the forum post mentioned by @joelretdev did end up creating the JavaScript / jQuery completions package they described and it does some of what you want.  It's called AndyJS2 and it is available via PackageControl.  The GitHub repo for the package is https://github.com/agibsonsw/AndyJS2.

(Assuming the forum poster / package creator are the same person because the same username [agibsonsw] is used on both sites and they clearly encountered the same issue.)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it seems that there is not a solid method of providing jQuery intellisense for SublimeText.

There is the jQuery package that you can obtain from the package manager or github: [jQuery Sublime](https://github.com/mrmartineau/jQuery), but it only provides snippets of course this is not what you really wanted.

I did, however, find a forum post on this matter that talks about adding a sublime-completions file to this package that could provide you with some intellisense. The only problem is that you have to define all the selectors/functions/events yourself in the file.

If you're interested, here is the post that details it: [SublimeText Forum](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5667&start=10)

I hope this helps, if I do find anything new I'll be sure to add an addendum to my post.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, there are not yet any good intellisense plugins for javascript in Sublime Text 2.

The snippets packages are not intellisense but simple autocompletions which do not take into account keywords, scope, or context.  In order to have a true intellisense solution for javascript, your script will need to be built on the fly - probably by a node.js process - and then a syntax tree constructed.

For now, you can use the SublimeLinter package which, when used on a machine with node.js installed, will show you JSHint errors as you type.  This isn't a perfect substitute, but the information provided is much more useful.